# Javascript working on xhtml but not on html

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

```
var obj = element;
while (obj.nodeName != 'p' && obj.nodeName != 'body') {
    obj = obj.parentNode;
}
if (obj.nodeName == 'p') {
     document.body.insertBefore(p, obj);
}
```

This is the code in my javaScript function. I create a `p` element and I insert it before the last `p` element found. This code is working on xhtml files but not on html files. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "It doesn't work" is *never* a good error description. Please describe what goes wrong, what error messages you get, etc.

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger to find out what is going wrong? Firebug is a good bet.

Comment: i'm not trying that on navigator, so i don't have so much informations .. but it work on xhtml and it's a good description so the problem is coming from coding or some thing close ..

Comment: i just used a debugger to give you more informations, that's the error 

    NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.

Comment: the problem is coming exactly from 
document.body.insertBefore(p, obj);
working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser is probably returning uppercase tag names when in HTML mode.

Use `nodeName.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Problem solved, the p element is not directly under the body that's why it don't find it in document.body, obj.parentNode work well.